# Eclipse content assist not working inside handlers/onclick

Tags: android, eclipse, onclick, handler, content-assist

For some reason, content assist will not work within any new object creation code that is written out. I honestly am not sure the exact name for the types of code where this occurs (im pretty sure there is a name but I simply cannot think of it). An example is included in the picture below.

[image: Broken Content Assist in Eclipse]

Notice the error at the bottom in red - this shows up every single time that content-assist doesnt work. However, this is an invalid error because as soon as I finish the line of code (manually of course), that goes away and I can even hover my mouse over the variables I used in that line and they show the pop-up that they normally would.

Any Help?

Answer (score 0):

Its a bug in Eclipse

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=367612

If your Inner class is not properly written you may face this issue

Answer (score 0):

According to the [android:id](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3aid) official info, you are missing something and obviously you can't `findViewById` inside that listener.

Try something like:

```
v.findViewById(R.id.you_view_id);
```

or:

```
enter code here`getActivity().findViewById(R.id.you_view_id);
```

Let me know about your progress ;)

Comment: That code works perfectly fine - its not broken. The reason its underlined in red is because eclipse things that the line I was typing on and the next non-commented line are the same. This is normal I think.

Comment: Yup. Done that already. The code works if im not trying to use content assist on a line. I think it is just an eclipse bug, one that will annoy me to no end.